# python error 403 while scraping angle list website

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I have watched other questions on stakeoverflow regarding HTTP 403 error however, have not found solution there.

i would like to change error from 403 to 200

trying to scrape this url `https://angel.co/startups`.

```
import requests
import random
my_session = requests.session()

for_cookies = my_session.get('https://angel.co/startups')
cookies = for_cookies.cookies

user_agents_list = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
     Mobile/15E148',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
     Chrome/99.0.4844.83 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
     Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
     Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',

]

response = my_session.get('https://angel.co/startups',cookies=cookies, headers={'User-Agent': 
random.choice(user_agents_list)})
print(response.text)
response.status_code #403
```

while running this code i am getting 403 error and instead of whole `HTML` page.

apart from that, i successfully managed to scrape 1st page using `cloudscraper` however, no idea how to scraper another pages.
[page format 1,2,3...2500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4dgR.png)

Comment: Do you know what `403` means? The HTTP `403 Forbidden` response status code indicates that the server understands the request but refuses to authorize it.

Comment: The site is detecting that youre a bot as per the `"https://ct.captcha-delivery.com/c.js`

Comment: yes i know what `403` means, that's why i want to convert this access to `200` which will allow me to scrape data, i have seen several questions for the same and converted into 200 request however that response didnt helped me. therefore raised a question. `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status` @baduker

Comment: @chitown88 yes, any idea how can web bypass google captcha ?

Comment: Well... `x-datadome: protected`. I doubt you will find the answer on an open forum.

Comment: Well, you're not really "converting" the response, rather than bypassing the bot detect. cloudscraper, as posted below is an option.

Comment: @chitown88  i tried with cloudscraper, yesterday was working fine however not working today. and shows 403

Answer (score -1):

It may be due to cloudflare protection or some sort of protection.

So, use cloudscraper to bypass it.

```
import cloudscraper

url = "https://angel.co/startups"
scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper()
response = scraper.get(url)
text = response.text
print(response.status_code)
```

Output

> 200

Comment: still 403 for me.

Comment: @vish let us know your mileage: after how many pages will you get 403 again?

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus scraping info from 1st page. will let you know if i get 403

Comment: was working fine yesterday, however when i opened up notebook and treid to run today it showed 403 error. any idea how to solve this ? i  have gone through various blogs and did sevral things none of them workout. @SagunDevkota

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus no, not working today, yesterday was working fine, shows 403 error